# Using Google geocode API with full address to return several values from JSON

Tags: json, google-geocoder

I receive the output of

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$address}
```

in JSON format. Then pull the latitude and longitude like this

```
$lati = $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
$longi = $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
```

All of which works great. But I also need the County name which is contained here

```
...
"results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Platte City",
               "short_name" : "Platte City",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Carroll Township",
               "short_name" : "Carroll Township",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Platte County",
               "short_name" : "Platte County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Missouri",
               "short_name" : "MO",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "64079",
               "short_name" : "64079",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
...
```

I tried

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
$type2 = $resp['results'][0]['address_components'][$i]['types'];
if (stripos(strtolower($type2), 'administrative_area_level_2') !== false){

    $county = $resp['results'][0]['address_components'][$i]['long_name'];

                } else {$county = "$i Unknown County";}
        }
```

As you can see County is in "administrative_area_level_2" but after trying for several hours all I get is 'Unknown County'. The Google API states that it will not always be in the same location in the XML/JSON and that seems to be correct. Sometimes its at position 3 sometimes at 5 sometimes other places. 
Can someone give me an example of how to get the County name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // Routine to find the County name
      foreach ($resp['results'][0]['address_components'] as $comp) {
        //loop through each component in ['address_components']     
        foreach ($comp['types'] as $currType){          
       //for every type in the current component, check if it = the check

        if($currType == 'administrative_area_level_2'){
            //echo $comp['long_name'];
                $county = $comp['long_name'];
                    }           }
            }
```